# Soundcloud api search no result

Tags: soundcloud

How does the Soundcloud search api work? I searched some songs and I get some results but, I just searched the word DJ SNAKE and I get no result. Why is that?

The link I used:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id={myID}&q=DJ%20SNAKE
```

Then I searched the word dj snake from the SoundCloud search bar, I get a lot of result. Why?

Answer (score 1):

(Posted as answer only for formatting)

This is interesting and looks like a bug to me.

First try it with linked_partitioning:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id={myID}&q=dj+snake&linked_partitioning=1
```

SoundCloud returns

```
{"collection":[],"next_href":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?linked_partitioning=1&client_id={myID}&offset=10&q=dj%20snake&limit=10"}
```

If you follow the next_href you find a DJ Snake track result, with another next_href to the next one.

For some reason, first page is empty, and each linked partition has only 1 result. That's not right....

When I try another search, I get a full page of results, as expected.

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id={myID}&q=black+crowes&linked_partitioning=1
```

Comment: I have not checked other one that give me the same problem and hope I won't get the second or third page results empty  for other search query. And it seems pretty fast to query 100 results.

Comment: Where did you get the api search parameters information ? From the official page I only see for libraries like Javascript, Python, Ruby (I don't wanna use libraries) from [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search) and for tracks [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks). But there is not those parameters.